# vuejs prerendering with php dynamic content

Tags: php, vue.js, seo, prerender

I have a Question about prerendering a vue app built with php ( laravel or pure php it doesn't matter ) 
My question is how really prerendering work with dynamic content **For example:**
when I make a blog with vue and php to show post I make Ajax Request in my vue app.. how google bots and other web crawlers will read my site content

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of prerendering is most used in SPA. It consists of rendering a placeholder or dynamic elements until the JavaScript code makes the necessary Ajax requests and uses the requested data to render new elements.

You can use prerendering to server-side render the HTML that you want to make indexable for the search engines. Using PHP and Vue.js to achieve that can be complex because you need to have a view for the PHP template engine and another one for Vue.js. It can be difficult to maintain when the application grows.

I've used [hypernova](https://github.com/airbnb/hypernova) to achieve that (Laravel and Vue.js). I wrote a couple of articles about it

https://dev.to/phillipgd1992/universal-rendering-in-laravel-using-vue-js-and-ara-framework-5amd

https://itnext.io/strangling-a-monolith-to-micro-frontends-decoupling-presentation-layer-18a33ddf591b

You can read more about prerender, ssr, csr and universal rendering here:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/rendering-on-the-web#seo

Let me know if I can help you with something else.